# WebStorm - HTML - Every word I type turns into an HTML tag, how do I stop it?

Tags: webstorm

I'm having this super annoying behavior with WebStorm. Every word I type and press space turns into a tag.

[image]

How do I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You must have `Space` specified as a key used to expand Emmet abbreviations. Please check **Preferences | Editor | Emmet, Expand abbreviation with** and **Preferences | Editor | Live Templates, By default expand with** options values